# jQuery rpg game movemen system

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am trying to do a little browser game with Javascript (jQuery). I have already fighting system and now I am trying to do movement system, so you can move around the world.

Let's say that I want to open map and go to town and then to shop. What is the best way to open MAP window and close all other windows, then open TOWN window and close MAP window, then open SHOP window and close TOWN window?

I tried something, but it feels a little bad.. Is this a good way to do it or not?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <style>
    .shopBox {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: none;
    }

    .mapBox {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: none;
    }

    .button {
        width: 50px;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px dashed black;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .shop {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        top: 100px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    </style>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#exit").hide();

        $("#mapBtn").click(function(){
            $("#map").show();
            $("#exit").show();
            $("#shop").hide();
            $("#mapBtn").hide();
        });

        $("#shopImg").click(function(){
            $("#map").hide();
            $("#shop").show();
            $("#exit").show();
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div class="button" id="mapBtn">Map</div>

    <div class="mapBox" id="map">
        This is your map
        <div class="shop" id="shopImg">Shop!!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="shopBox" id="shop">Welcome to my shop!</div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written looks functional. I don't see any problems. The only issue you will encounter is when you start introducing more details and complexity.

Just make sure you start making these into functions with annotations otherwise you will get lost.

An aside, consider the Unity Development Platform or Flash or consider using libraries which will save you a great deal of time: for example. [Crafty](http://craftyjs.com/)

Otherwise, you'll learn as you'll continue coding. Focus on functionality and then optimization. Doing both with limited experience can be counterproductive.

Cheeers

Comment: I think since OP doesn't have a concrete issue to fix, and is just looking for help with methodology, this is the best advice. Also: "Focus on functionality and then optimization. Doing both with limited experience can be counterproductive." Yes; even doing both with extensive experience can be counterproductive. You learn as you go, all the time.

Answer (score 0):

you can select multiple elements at the same time like this

```
 $("#mapBtn").click(function(){
        $("#map, #exit").show();
        $("#shop, #mapBtn").hide();
    });
```

that will at least save you some space.